# Azure upload file from an external computer

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I'm want to upload file to azure blob storage via c# from an external computer which is not part of azure system (simply my own computer). I found only [Microsoft example](http://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) for azure cloud services.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Visual studion server explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx) to load manualy or write code.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference("blobname");
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream); //stream of file
```

Another way using [Azure storage power shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408487.aspx)

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container containerName -File .\filename -Blob blobname
```

Comment: I attached a azure to my solution. How i can get CloudStorageAccount through it? In example they use connection string, but i can't use it.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can upload to blob storage from anywhere.  Doesn't have to be part of the azure infrastructure.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a code example, or an explanation of how that might be done?

Comment: Well, he referenced a link that has detailed instructions on how to upload a blob.  Just answering that he could do that from anywhere.